# Lazy loading in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

There are doubts about **lazy loading** in AngularDart between `*deferredContent` and `@deferred`.

[AppLayout](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/angular_components/lib/app_layout#persistent-drawers) component we have the `*deferredContent` use.

[Github](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/issues/406) we have the `@deferred` implementation discution.

*What is the difference between them?*

I didn't find the detailed documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

These are two very different concepts that happen to have a similar name.

*deferredContent is not for lazy loading. It is for not change detecting content that are hidden.

The way angular works the content passed to certain components like app-bar live in the parent, and not a child of the app-bar. Thus the app-bar can't by itself control when change detection happens on that content. To get around this we use *deferredContent to allow the content to be removed from the widget tree when the drawer is closed, and so not seen.

It is the equivalent to a *ngIf="visible" in many contexts.

I think both @deffered, and *deferredContent could be used at the same time, but I probably wouldn't suggest lazy loading to that level as I would expect app bar content to be needed pretty quickly after the app is loaded.

More info here: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/37b2b4b940d91747678bd18e29c55c8a876498ee/angular_components/lib/content/deferred_content.dart#L18 Notice it doesn't say anything about lazy loading, just creation.

Comment: It's clear the `*deferredContent` behaviour. What about `@deferred`, is there any documentation with more detail? (best practice when use it or not, when the component starts loading, etc.)